# Eager Loading Association w/ Default Scope Causes Incorrect Table Alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 models:

```
class Company
  has_many :products
  has_many :variants, through: :products
end

class Product
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :variants
end

class Variant
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I am using the paranoia gem which adds a default scope to each model:

```
default_scope { where deleted_at: nil }
```

When I attempt to do a query:

```
company.variants.includes(:product).references(:products).where('products.name ilike ?', "%test%")
```

I get an error:

PG::UndefinedTable - ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "products"
LINE 1: ...ucts_variants"."id" = "variants"."product_id" AND "products"...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "products_variants".

Full Query:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "variants" INNER JOIN "products" "products_variants" ON "products_variants"."id" = "variants"."product_id" AND "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "prices" ON "prices"."variant_id" = "variants"."id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "variants"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "products"."company_id" = $1

If I remove the acts_as_paranoid from the Product and Variant models, it works fine. I guess the condition on the table somehow causes AR to create a table alias. Is this a bug in rails? How can I fix it? Thanks.